# Read-only date field on IOS browser?

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, html, safari

Readonly fields don't seem to work on iOS. This is what I have:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "true" } })
```

Essentially, this gets translated to this:

```
<input type="date" readonly="readonly" />
```

Works on Windows Chrome, but does does not work on the iPhone. Still able to edit the field. The date picker shows up.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a bug in iOS, a readonly date field is still changeable.

You can fix it by adding something like this to the HTML:

```
onclick="this.blur()"
```

Comment: This is seriously still not fixed in 2020?

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this.  Solved it by making it type="text" when I am rendering it as read-only mode.

Comment: I feel this should be accepted answer.  :-D

Comment: The problem is it then renders the date in the yyyy-MM-dd format.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `input` tag to this

```
<input type="date" readonly />
```

[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25928605/in-ios8-safari-readonly-inputs-are-handled-incorrectly) too, maybe is an iOS bug.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `disabled` attribute instead of `readonly`.

```html
<input type="date" disabled />
```