# How can I make the readonly attribute work in mobile phones?

Tags: html, css

I have an input `<input class="form-control" readonly>`.

On desktop browsers, I get the expected behaviour: The input cannot be clicked/focused.

But in mobile phones (currently only tested on iOS/Safari) I get the following behaviour when I tap the input field:

[image]

As you can see several things are happening. A text cursor is shown in the input field, the application is zoomed in, a bottom bar is shown. How can I prevent the input element from receiving focus like this in mobile phones?

**EDIT: The suggested duplicate doesn't solve my problem.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In iOS8 Safari, readonly inputs are handled incorrectly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25928605/in-ios8-safari-readonly-inputs-are-handled-incorrectly)

Comment: It is probably better to use the disabled tag read only keeps most of the interactions of input fields alive.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to just avoid any interactions with certain HTML element, try following:

```
/* CSS */
.__readonly {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

And in HTML:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input class="form-control __readonly" readonly />
```